# How to increase the corner's selection area of a rect in Fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

Firstly,  I load a image with large size in Fabric.

Then I add a rect object to it。

I find it is hard to select the corner of the rect, even if I increase the size of the rect's corner

how to increase the selection area of the corner ?

p.s on mobile device

Finally， I read the source code, and find the property: touchCornerSize